# Как сделать Input в телеграм боте на aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Нужно сделать ввод пользователя в телеграм на aiogram. Раньше использовал telebot, но потом перешёл на aiogram.
Со старого кода у меня остался input, но он не работает потому что в aiogram чуть-чуть другие функции.
Вот этот фрагмент кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True) def messages(message):   
if 'Принято!' in message.text:
    Good(message)   
else:
    No(message)
```

Comment: message.text это и есть сообщение введение пользователем

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler():
async def messages(message: types.Message):
    if 'Принято!' in message.text:
        await message.answer('Good!')
    else:
        await message.answer('Bad')
```

Вы плохо сформулировали вопрос, возможно я не правильно понял что вам нужно